# How can i resolve error with fill property after upgrading react-native-svg from 12.3.0 to 13.4.0?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-svg

I built React Native app, and I'm using Expo SDK 48 (requires react-native-svg@13.4.0), after I upgrade react-native-svg package to the latest version, although I use the fill property correctly, I have this strange error:

```
Error while updating property 'fill' of a view managed by: RNSVGPath

null

java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

This is my package.json:

```
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.6",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
```

This is one example of how I use the fill property:

```
<Svg width={12.091} height={13.098} {...props}>
      <Path
d="M11.083 1.008H9.068V0H8.061v1.008H4.03V0H3.023v1.008H1.008A1.01 1.01 0 000 2.015v10.076a1.01  1.01 0 001.008 1.008h10.075a1.01 1.01 0 001.008-1.008V2.015a1.01 1.01 0 00-1.008-1.007zm0 11.083H1.008V5.038h10.075zm0-8.061H1.008V2.015h2.015v1.008H4.03V2.015h4.03v1.008h1.008V2.015h2.015z"
        fill={colors.gray[400]}
      />
</Svg>
<Svg width={17.811} height={17.811} {...svgProps}>
      <Path
        data-name="Path 14499"
        d="M7.132.75a6.382 6.382 0 106.382 6.382A6.382 6.382 0 007.132.75z"
        fill="none"
        stroke={color ?? colors.gray[400]}
        strokeMiterlimit={10}
        strokeWidth={1.5}
      />
      <Path
        data-name="Path 14500"
        d="M12.293 12.293l4.457 4.457"
        strokeLinecap="round"
        fill="transparent"
        stroke={color ?? colors.gray[400]}
        strokeMiterlimit={10}
        strokeWidth={1.5}
      />
</Svg>
```

I tried to reinstall the library and then install it again, to clear the Expo and React Native cache, I tried to use fill without a variable but with the right value for the colors, but none of that worked, I don't know what to try anymore.

Comment: Similar issue in expo github https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20983

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded it to v12.5.1 It is still working. There is no reason to upgrade. It still works well. The Expo doctor throw a warn only.

Comment: Now I use the newest version with Expo SDK 48 and It works well